# Laravel eloquent apply whereHas on latest record of hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship, laravel-7

Using Laravel 7.0

I have 3 models (**Meeting**, **MeetingVersion**, and **User**), 
and 4 tables (**Meeting**, **meeting_versions**, **users**, **meeting_versions_users**).

A **Meeting** has many **MeetingVersion** models, in which each version has a `many-to-many` relationship with **User**. Each **MeetingVersion** has a foreign key `meeting_id` to its parent **Meeting**. Users are associated to a MeetingVersion through the `meeting_versions_users` pivot table.

Now, I want to select all Meetings where the latest version is associated with a given user id.

#### Meeting Class

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MeetingVersion::class, 'meeting_id');
}
```

#### MeetingVersion Class

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'meeting_versions_users', 'version_id', 'user_id');
}
```

### Tables

**Meeting**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 10 |
| 11 |
+----+
```

**meeting_versions**

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | meeting_id | version |
+----+------------+---------+
| 31 |         10 |       1 |
| 32 |         10 |       2 |
| 33 |         10 |       3 | <- latest version (33) for meeting id 10
| 34 |         11 |       1 |
| 35 |         11 |       2 | <- latest version (35) for meeting id 11
+----+------------+---------+
```

**meeting_versions_users**

```
+------------+---------+
| version_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+
|         31 |     101 |
|         32 |     101 |
|         33 |     102 | <- user associated with latest version for meeting id 10
|         34 |     101 |
|         35 |     101 | <- user associated with latest version for meeting id 11
+------------+---------+
```

**users**

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 101 |
| 102 |
+-----+
```

Here's the Query I'm trying. I should only get back meeting 11, but this query is returning both meetings for user 101.

```
// Some user id.
$userId = 101;


// Query to get all meetings where user is associated with latest version of meeting.

$meeting = Meeting::query()->where(function (Builder $query) use ($userId) {

        $query->whereHas('versions', function (Builder $query) use ($userId) {

            /*
             * I want to get just the "latest" version model here, so that further queries are constrained to that model only.
             * As it is now, the below whereHas query is applied to all child models.
             * Using $query->latest('version')->limit(1) doesn't work here as expected.
             *
             * So, I need to a way to limit the following whereHas query to the latest version.
             * This constraint should be applied to just the "latest" model relation, instead of all models.
            */

            $query->whereHas('users', function (Builder $query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('id', $userId);
            });

        });
    })->get();
```

Any help with this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your question you said:

> - Using $query->latest('version')->limit(1) doesn't work here as expected.

because laravel get last MeetingVersion of the entire query! not for every Meeting

to solve this use [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

then in Meeting Model:

```
class Meeting extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
.....
public function lastMeetingVersion()
{
return $this->hasMany(MeetingVersion::class, 'meeting_id')
->orderBy('id','desc')->limit(1);
}
    }
```

and in MeetingVersion:

```
class MeetingVersion extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
......
}
```

now the limit will work as you expected ....

```
$meeting = Meeting::query()->with(['lastMeetingVersion' => function ($query)
        use ($userId) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
                $q->where('id', $userId);
            });
        }]);
```

more details in: [eloquent-eager-limit](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

Comment: Thanks, OMR.  I tried this solution, but I didn't work either. When adding a `->get()` to the end of this query, I got a memory has been exhausted error. I also just tried to use `->find(10)`, which returns a result, but does so for both users, instead of user user 102.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subselect to get the max version id of each meeting.

```php
$meetings = Meeting::query()
    ->whereHas('versions', function (Builder $query) use ($userId) {
        $query->addSelect([
            'max_meeting_version_id' => MeetingVersion::select('id')->whereColumn('meeting_id', 'meeting.id')
                ->orderBy('version', 'desc')->limit(1)
        ])->whereHas('users', function (Builder $query2) use ($userId) {
            $query2->where('users.id', $userId);
        })
            ->havingRaw('max_meeting_version_id = meeting_versions.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, bangnokia. I tried this, but I'm getting an error in the `havingRaw` clause.


"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'meeting_versions.id' in 'having clause' "

I tried changing the clause to 'max_meeting_version_id = id', which prevented the erorr. However, now it's not producing any results.

Comment: Do you have laravel debug bar, it's can show you the raw sql query. I'm not sure why `meeting_versions.id` is unknow.